# Is it possible to retrieve only selected messages from Whatsapp via Python?

Tags: python, nlp, twilio, whatsapp

I'm working on a project, where I want to analyze text messages from Whatsapp via Python to see if they indicate that a person shows signs of chronic stress. For this, the user should choose if all messages should be used or select only certain messages that are crucial for the analysis. My goal is to obtain messages and feed them into an ML model to classify the text. After that, an analysis will be performed and the user will be informed when the analysis is finished.

Now I'm looking at potential libraries that could help me retrieve these messages. Unfortunately, the ones that I found are missing some of the key functionality that I require:

[WhatSoup](https://github.com/eddyharrington/WhatSoup) - exports the entire chat of a WhatsApp conversation and saves it into a .txt, .csv or .HTML file. While that would be more than enough, I want to allow the user also to only export certain messages, if required, and not the whole chat from a certain date.

[Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/quickstart/python) - enables applications to send and retrieve messages. While the sending part would be nice, there does not seem to be an option to select messages from the chats that should be retrieved.

[WebWhatsApp-Wrapper](https://github.com/mukulhase/WebWhatsapp-Wrapper) - is similar to Twilio but with more functionalities. But the function to let the user select specific messages is not implemented.

Does anybody know how I could achieve my idea?

I would appreciate any input :)

Comment: I mean You could allow users to copy the necessary messages themselves and paste into Your application

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I don't believe the Twilio API is for your use-case here. The Twilio API for WhatsApp wraps the WhatsApp Business API and allows you to send and receive messages from a number that is verified as a WhatsApp Business number. It cannot be used to fetch messages from a user. WhatsApp does not really intend for other applications to extract messages, so you might find this a challenge in general.